# Can't access nginx server in local network, android

Tags: android, nginx

My problem is that my phone can't access server in local network which uses nginx

I can access it from my machine directly, as well as I can from genymotion emulator:
[image]

But my android phone (7.1.2 N2G47H; Redmi Note 5A Build) is fails to load it. It's stuck in loading, until browser (Chrome 68.9.3440.91) says that response time was exceeded.

I was trying to access server via IP of my machine in local network (192.168.1.123)

However, if I serve files using [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) module from python, it works fine, files are served.

nginx.conf:

```
user tauyekel staff;
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;

    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/x-component;

    server {
        listen *:80;

        # serve static files
        location ~ ^/.*$ {
            root /Users/tauyekel/Documents/webprojects/mobile-test;
        }
    }
}
```

My directory with static files consists of single `index.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Mobile Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Tauka!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

No luck with iOS device either

I will appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but I wonder how does your phone connect to your network? Your computer connects to it via an ethernet cable or wi-fi. That assigns it an IP address within the network and the connection can be resolved. Is your phone using wi-fi too? Or are you just opening a browser window and typing in the IP address? Without a wi-fi connection to your local network, the phone will use the cell phone provider's network connectivity to get to the internet. The problem is that your computer IP address 192.168.1.123 is a private network address and can't be reached from the internet.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but yes, I'm connecting to my home network via wi-fi. It works with python simple server, but not with nginx